# IO Exception, my program with input data of x,y sometimes works without any error and randomly sometimes doesnt work with the same x,y input data

Tags: java, jsoup, ioexception

i am looping a method with a Thread which reads from a website(dynamically)
all the methods work perfectly, but my problem is that sometimes (3 out of 10 times) that i start the program it throws IO exception at me although i haven't changed my input data from the last known good execution , the exception is coming from the method below:

```
public String readThisUrlContent() throws ExceptionHandler
{

    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(1000).get();
        return doc.body().text();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ExceptionHandler("IO Exception for reading the site in method setUrlContent in Url class");
    }

}
```

my best guess is that since i'm reading more than one Url with looping this method but the timeout is not sometimes at the best range (considering the internet speed etc. it sometimes doesn't work) but its just my theory and it can be dead wrong but even if its correct i have no idea how to handle it

Comment: What about trying to use a greater timeout value maybe 2 or 5 seconds?

Comment: `but it is just my theory`. It is an easy to test one. Increase timeout and see what happens.

Comment: What exactly IOException are you getting? Did you ever close the resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem exactly was the time to live of the opened port. since i had other functions working at the same time program simply needed more connected time so i expanded timeout to (5000) and also reduced the timer of another Time.Schedule method in another method, and so it worked